# Generic decimal can't cast from double

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I don't see why this is not working, I can do a direct cast from `double` to `decimal` with no problem, but unexpectedly I can't do this cast if it is inside a generic class, this snippet explains it better:

```
public class TestCollection<T>
{
    public void Add(object value)
    {
        //When T is decimal, then I get 
        // System.InvalidCastException
        var t = (T) value;
    }
}

public void Main ()
{
    var t = new TestCollection<decimal> ();
    double doub = 10;

    var decim = (decimal) doub; //Works!       
    t.Add(doub);                //throws!
}
```

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2147467262
>     Message=Specified cast is not valid.
>     Source=Wpf
>     StackTrace:
>          at Wpf.TestCollection`1.Add(Object value) in C:\Users\btord\Source\Repos\Live-Charts\Examples\Wpf\JimmyTheTestsGuy.xaml.cs:line 15
>          at Wpf.JimmyTheTestsGuy..ctor() in C:\Users\btord\Source\Repos\Live-Charts\Examples\Wpf\JimmyTheTestsGuy.xaml.cs:line 35
>          at Wpf.MainWindow..ctor() in C:\Users\btord\Source\Repos\Live-Charts\Examples\Wpf\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 56
>     InnerException:

Comment: This happens because you pass the object, not double.

Comment: Why is the type of `value` `object` and not `T`?

Comment: @Lee I have 2 overloads, one for T and one for object, I get the error when the object overload is called, this is a small part of the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails due to the exact same reason why the following fails:

```
short s = 1;
object o = s;
var i = (int)o; //Runtime error
```

The reason being that a boxed value can only be unboxed to its real type. In your case your are boxing a `double` and trying to unbox it to a `decimal`. That is not allowed.

I'd push back on the whole design. You have a generic collection of `T`s. Your `Add` method should simply accept `T`s and let the caller carry the burden of converting to the right type. If that's not a valid solution then get rid of generics all together and simply implement a collection of objects.

Comment: @bto.rdz `public void Add(dynamic value)` seems to work, if you're OK with `dynamic`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `Convert.ChangeType` for that:

```
public void Add(object value)
{
    var t = Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

See the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Tfgyz

Comment: Thanks, I am worried about the perfomance with this method, since this method is really important in my code

Comment: Ok. Maybe you should profile it first to see if it is a no go. Just found a stackoverflow answer which deals with the performance of `ChangeType`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532197/faster-version-of-convert-changetype

Answer (score 1):

If you need object insead of T you can use dynamic in your Add method.

```
 public void Add(object value)
 {
      //When T is decimal, then I get 
      // System.InvalidCastException
      dynamic t1 = value;
      var t = (T)t1;
 }
```